# How can I make my code for calculating what is the minimum possible ways to divide each item by 2 faster?

Tags: python, algorithm

Giving a list of numbers `A`, the goal is to find the minimum possible number of divisions you can do on each item to get an `x` in which `x <= sum(A)/2`.

For example,

- if `A = [10,10]` you can divide the `A[0]` by 2 and you can divide `A[1]` by 2 as well to get half of the sum of the list. So, the minimum possible number of divisions equals to `2`,
- if `A = [200, 25,25,25]` you can divide `A[0]/2^2` so `x =[50,25,25,25]` which sum to `125 <= 275` so minimum possible number of divisions equals to `3`.

I tried the following way and it works just fine, but when I input huage lists like this `get_f([200,25,25,25,490,99999, 2000, 43002])` I got timeout error.

```
import itertools

def get_f(A):
    
  A = sorted(A)[::-1]
  Goal = sum(A)/2

  filters = []
  x = itertools.product(range(len(A)), repeat=len(A))
  for i in x:
    i = list(i)
    C = A.copy()
    x = 0
    for Index in i:
      C[Index]/=2
      x+=1
      if sum(C) <= Goal and x not in filters:
        filters.append(x)
  return sorted(filters)[0]
```

Comment: sum([200, 25, 25, 25])/ 2 = 137.5. This should be solvable with 2 divisions: sum([50, 25, 25, 25]) = 125 <= 137.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The currently accepted solution is incorrect- it will, for instance, never return a number larger than the length of the input list, regardless of how large any of those numbers are.

The optimal way to approach this problem is with a priority queue- allowing you to avoid recomputing the `max()` (as done in another answer) over and over.

Code:

```
from heapq import heapify, heappop, heappush
from itertools import count
from math import isclose

def solve(nums):
    heap = [-x for x in nums]
    heapify(heap)

    total = sum(nums)
    target = total / 2

    for divs in count():
        if total < target or isclose(total, target):
            return divs
        
        delta = heappop(heap) / 2
        total += delta
        heappush(heap, delta)
```

Demo:

```
>>> print(solve([200, 25, 25, 25]))
2
>>> print(solve([200, 25, 25, 25, 0]))
2
>>> print(solve([100, 25, 100, 25]))
3
```

*Note*: the original example in the problem statement is wrong- you can divide 200 by 2 twice, and the sum `[50, 25, 25, 25] = 125` is less than the original sum `275`, making the answer `2`, not `3`.

Comment: Is there a way to do it with pure python without `heapq` @Dillon Davis

Comment: `heapq` is a builtin library that comes with python. You could also use `queue` (another builtin module) which offers similar functionality.

Comment: there is another way using recursion @Dillon Davis [like this](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1gCFZHHJ8Wes2zIE_O2a0DROMT0Kv4lgu)

Comment: @alial-karaawi that code doesn't work when I run it- I get `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`

Comment: Yes it does not work, but the idea is using something like it (recursion)

Comment: @alial-karaawi that will not be any faster than an imperative loop, and you'd still need a heap to make it work (at least maintaining that time complexity). Also, another heads up- watch out for recursion in python, even working algorithms sometimes break on large enough inputs due to the recursion depth issue.

Comment: I see but isn't this issue the same as the famous [coin change problem](https://www.techiedelight.com/coin-change-problem-find-total-number-ways-get-denomination-coins/)

Comment: @alial-karaawi it is not. The values of the coins (array elems being divided and subtracted) change as you pick coins.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version of the code. It works just fine on the tests. Check it out.

```py
def get_f(A):
    """
    A: list of numbers
    return: int
    """
    x = sum(A) // 2
    if x == 0:
        return 0
    count = 0
    for i in A:
        if i <= x:
            count += 1
    return count

print(get_f([10,10]))
print(get_f([200, 25,25,25]))
print(get_f([10,10,10]))
print(get_f([10,10,10,10]))
print(get_f([200,25,25,25,490,99999, 2000, 43002]))
```

Hope this is what you were looking for

Comment: This is **wrong**. Take `[200, 25,25,25,0]` as an example-  outputs `4` instead of `3`